# How to align this textView to center vertically?

Tags: android, xml, textview, vertical-alignment

Okay, so I have this issue: [image]

I am going mad since I have been trying to find the answer for this issue for about 3 hours now.
Anyways, I want to align first textView (as seen in the picture) to center vertically.
I am creating these textViews programatically (no need to ask why, I just have to).
Code:

```
private View formTextViewUnits(String units) {
    TextView textViewUnits = new TextView(getActivity());
    textViewUnits.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    textViewUnits.setText(units);
    textViewUnits.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    textViewUnits.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#e9e9e9"));
    textViewUnits.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.main_stripe_small_text));

    return textViewUnits;
}

private View formTextViewAmount(Float amount) {
    TextView textViewAmount = new TextView(getActivity());
    textViewAmount.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    textViewAmount.setText(amount.toString());
    textViewAmount.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    textViewAmount.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#3ebce6"));
    textViewAmount.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.main_stripe_big_text));

    return textViewAmount;
}

//THIS IS THE FAULTY TEXTVIEW
private View formTextViewMessage(String message) {
    TextView textViewMessage = new TextView(getActivity());
    textViewMessage.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    textViewMessage.setText(message);
    textViewMessage.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    textViewMessage.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#e9e9e9"));
    textViewMessage.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.main_stripe_small_text));

    return textViewMessage;
}
```

And here is my fragments table row (using tableLayout) for it:

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/main_stripe_padding_top"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/main_stripe_padding_bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/main_stripe_margin_bottom"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="#424242">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_span="2"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/main_stripe_text_padding_left"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/main_stripe_text_padding_right"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutStripe">
    </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TextView.setGravity(...)` sets the gravity of the text *inside the bounds of your `TextView`*. Since the `TextView` in question has its vertical height to `wrap_content`, the bounds of the view will always be the height of the content anyway.

If you set the height of your `TextView` to `match_parent`, and keep the gravity setting as you have now, the text in your `TextView` should appear vertically centered in its parent layout.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried that: `textViewMessage.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));`
But this is what happened (sorry for external link): https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Camera%20Uploads/2014-01-30%2016.09.39.png?_subject_uid=99305133&w=AAAGpTu_QjGqACwiwExyXOMiGEkGl2scSSLDUYrccAartw

Comment: Fixed it by adding gravity arguments for linear_layout in fragment :)